# US airline is making it impossible for me to get a refund for my refundable ticket

Tags: usa, passenger-rights, jetblue

I bought a refundable ticket with JetBlue. I tried to refund it by going to the 'Manage My Booking' page and selecting 'Cancel Booking'. However, the website gave me an error message saying, "This part of our site is not working right now. Please call us." I called them and was told the estimated wait time was over 360 minutes. I have been on hold for a while, but it is unreasonable to expect any adult to spend that much time on hold. Do I have any rights in this situation, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them via email, contact form or social media (by private messages) or other "asynchronous" communication?

Comment: If you paid by card, contact the card provider.

Comment: @WeatherVane contact the airline by email before doing a chargeback though and give them a reasonable time to respond.

Comment: "expect any adult to spend that much time on hold." Ah, get a kid to wait for you then?